# First time using ZFS or RAID: Data Backup

Tags: backup, raid, zfs

I've never used RAID before or ZFS for that matter, though I've always admired them. I've been using MX Linux for 2 years, so I'm still pretty fresh to deep Linux.

My idea is for a long-term backup of a large amount of data. (Forgetting the 3-2-1 backup rule for the moment). say the setup was a computer with 4x8tb drives. My idea is have the data on ZFS file system and run a Cyclical Redundancy Check periodically between the RAID 1 drives, and if an error is detected, then copy over-write the correct data from the alternate RAID 1 drive.

Say I turn the PC on once every 3 years just to run though the data checks and make corrections then turn off again.

Is this feasible in concept? Has anyone ever done anything like this? If so, how simple can it be, can it be automated?

Comment: longterm backup will never be done with harddrives

Comment: ZFS has crc built in, it does what you are describing automatically with its periodic scrubs.  RAID is only a partial mitigation for hardware failure.  ZFS checkpointing with scheduled checkponts can be a good backup method for the purpose of rolling back mistakes, but it won't mitigate for N+1 drive failure, controller failure, or system failure.

Comment: @djdomi it may, but with more control then the described setup. Have 3-4 copies, scrubbing and automatic replication, and you can rely on unreliable storage media.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Okay, hypothetically say I have 8tb of data over 32tb of drives using the RAID number of whatever you suggest. My concern is does the ZFS scrub only check the checksum, or is it actually going to make a comparison between the data and the databackup to identify when some data goes bad and correct the error? Also, what role do the SMART tools play in this endevour? And finally, is there any guide I can follow which will begin this journey? Thanks

Comment: P.S. Actually replace 8tb above, with '16tb data', and I'm thinking a RAID 10. I'm concerned with checking for more than just bad sectors, but like bit-rot too. Cheers

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding something - ZFS is software-RAID and already has redundancy built-in _(it's a self-healing filesystem with parity)_, whereas RAID usually refers to hardware-RAID _(intermingling ZFS and RAID only sows confusion)_. It's recommended to scrub your [ZFS] zpools on a set schedule via a cron job, usually once every week _(the FreeNAS and FreeBSD forums are great reference mediums)_. In general, ZFS is superior to hardware-RAID in most ways.

Comment: Hi JW0914, thanks for the great reply. I didn't understand the difference, thanks for clarifying RAID. On a debian distro would FreeNAS be the software you'd use for the zpool? So does the zfs generate the checksum from the actual data in the zpool? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum level of reliability you get with a mirror (ie 2 disks, with zfs it is also possible to put 3 or more) and the checksum activated (default situation).
By running a periodic scrub (every day, every month ...) you can verify that both copies, or rather the relative checksums, are intact, without having to do anything more than a crontab.

Regarding a long-term content verification (even for voluntary changes) I would use zpaq / zpaqfranz to archive a copy with its SHA1 hashes and CRC-32 checksums.

In this way you can (with the command l, list) compare the archived copy with the current data at any time, being 100% sure that they are identical.

Alongside such a situation I would add an optical copy mechanism (yes, on BDXLs of 100GB each) with archivers (eg zpaqfranz, 7z ...) able to verify that the data has not been modified.
However, this is a read-only situation, ie the archive, once written, is no longer modified

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Can you please indulge my ignorance and clarify, does the zfs checksum actually generate based on the data? Also, did you have any choice resources to read about zpaqfranz? I'm interested but don't know where to start. Thanks very much!

Comment: zfs make checksum for about everything, data and metadata. You can easily check with zfs get checksum nameofthepool. On openzfs (FreeBSD 13+, newer Linux) you can choose between algorithms. You can find zpaqfranz on github https://github.com/fcorbelli/zpaqfranz or sourceforge

Comment: Hi Franco, So using zpaq / zpaqfranz I can run a checksum to make sure the data is still in-tact over time; however, openzfs should do this on the zpool periodically anyway? So reading about zpaq the big advantage for archival is that it will only update data where changes have been made? When I read your last message I thought you meant like it will check what was written (e.g. to a BDXL) to ensure it was written correctly, however I now assume that is done by default by any programme writing to a medium? Thanks very much!

Comment: With zpaqfranz you can verify of SHA-1 blocks of the file AND the CRC-32 of the entire file (zpaq only SHA-1). You can do the same with, for example, 7z but only for CRC-32 checksum. Of course if you have READ ONLY data you can write into a "safe" medium (AKA: DVD-R, BD-R, BDXL depending on the space needed) together with one o more hash list. So you have 3 situations: 1) the "live" data. zfs checksum almost everything, zpool scrub to check. 2) backup data: use for example zpaqfranz on USB drive (more than one!), OK with zfs snapshots 3) read only (long term store): optical media if possible

Comment: Another excellent reply Franco. Elaborating on your clarification of the 3 situations; so regarding the first and second: If it's live data, openzfs will take care of everything via zpool scrub. If it's backup data then use zpaqfranz for periodic backups, rather than say rsync?? Thanks again

Comment: openzfs is the "merge" of "old" zfs (unix) with "new" (linux). For periodic backup you can try zpaqfranz (instead of rsync) because it keep "snapshots" of the data forever. With rsync (or tar, 7z, rar...) you get only ONE version of your data. With zpaqfranz even thousands (think as a "snapshotted" archive). Just try: it is opensource, no money needed

Comment: Thanks Franco, I look forward to trying zpaqfran. All the best